# Batch convert Excel to PDF in Java using PDF printer

Tags: java, excel, pdf

I would like to batch convert some Excels to PDFs. I researched a little bit. Making it by ApachePOI doesn't make much sense for me, because I have a lot of formatting, tables, colors, etc.
Is there any possibility to convert it by e.g. doPDF printer? Can it by converted in command line?

Comment: You can use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to launch arbitrary commands

Comment: Thanks, but my question was rather how to use command line to batch convert to pdfs. Which printer etc I could use

Comment: Then I'm sorry but it's not relevant to stackoverflow :-/ I'm sure a quick google search on "pdf printer command-line arguments" should give you a few potential solutions though